# Solve $7 x^{2} y^{2}+4 x^{2}=77 y^{2}+1260$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

**Attempt**:

$$4 x^{2}=7(11 y^{2}-x^{2} y^{2}+180)$$

$$\implies x=7u\quad(u\in \mathbb{Z})$$

$$11 y^{2}-49 u^{2} y^{2}+180=28 u^{2}$$

$$y^{2}=\frac{28 u^{2}-180}{11-49 u^{2}} \geqslant 0$$

$$u=0, \pm 1 ; \pm 2 \quad u^{2}=1 \implies y^{2}=4$$

$$ (x, y) \in\{(7,2) ;(-7,-2) ;(-7,2) ;(7,-2)\}.$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Rewrite as $$(7y^2+4)(x^2-11)=1260-44=1216=19\cdot 2^6$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, acronyms aside, the OP's approach looks more efficient to me here. I don't see any super quick way to get from your factorization to the (essentially unique) answer. The requirement $7y^2+4\le1216$ says $|y|\le13$, but that still leaves a bunch of cases to consider. Is there something slick I'm overlooking?

Comment: @BarryCipra Well, the possible values of these factors are $\pm1, \pm2, \pm4, \pm8, \pm16,\pm 19, \pm32, \pm38, \pm64, \pm76, \pm152, \pm304, \pm608, \pm1216$. And only $-2$ and $38$ work.

Comment: @BarryCipra Umm, you actually don't have to consider all of them. We are working with integers, so we can look for factors here that are $11$ less than a square.

Comment: @BarryCipra The inequality also holds for $u=\pm2$. And there aren't many factors to try as the factor $7y^2+4$ is congruent to $4$ mod $7$, and the factor $x^2-11$ is $11$ less than a perfect square. Considering either of these two restrictions already greatly reduces the number of factors to consider.

Comment: @Servaes, oh yes, you're right. I miscalculated something. I'll delete that boneheaded comment.

Comment: @Cornifer, I deleted my earlier reply because it referred to another comment I deleted, but will repeat the essential point, which is that the OP's approach involves less consideration of cases.

Comment: @BarryCipra And I don’t argue) I just said that not everything is as gloomy as you described it)

Comment: Well, $x^2-11$ is never $\pm 19,\pm 1$ nor a multiple of $4.$ so you really don't have many cases to consider with my approach.  $x^2-11=\pm 38$ is the only option. @BarryCipra $-38$ is not an option/

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I guess we first check the quadratic residues mod 19 and notice that the first factor is not divisible by 4.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, ah I see it now: You use the fact that $11$ is not a quadratic residue mod $4$ to rule out everything for $x^2-11$ but $1$, $2$, $19$ and $38$. (Negative factors are ruled out by the fact that the other factor, $7y^2+4$, is always positive.) Then it's quick to see that only $38$ plus $11$ is a square. It was the nonresidue-mod-4 observation that escaped me. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution would be improved by explaining what your solution is. As it stands, it is simply a sequence of formal expressions. It is not always clear how these relate to each other. The greatest leap is from $y^2\geq0$ to $|u|\leq2$. As a general rule of thumb, every expression you write down is in fact a claim, which usually requires some sort of argument.

Comment: "The greatest leap is from $y^2≥0$ to $|u|≤2$." I wouldn't call it a leap, he/she just solved the inequality $\frac{28 u^{2}-180}{11-49 u^{2}} \geq 0$.

Comment: @Cornifer I'd call every step a leap, as I have to guess how each expression follows from the previous one. But that's semantics, I guess.

Comment: @Cornifer. The proposer has not given any details to explain how $(28-u^2)/(11-49u^2)\ge 0$ implies $|u|\le 2$ and not explained why $0\ne |u|\ne 2$. Even simple or obvious inferences need justifying, to ensure no mistakes.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It immediately strikes the eye that the denominator is negative, and then a restriction on $|u|$ is obtained. My criterion in this regard is this: if I can easily check the statements made, then everything is fine.